# Server Manager 2012

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, windows

In Server 2008 R2 the Server Manager instance was an all-inclusive tool with which to do everything from a centralized location - IIS, MSMQ, Event Viewer, Services, Disk Management, etc. In Server 2012 the new Server Manager doesn't seem to have the ability to do any of this natively without creating custom MMCs like in the old days.

Am I just missing something or did they really remove this?

Comment: In Server Manager go to the Tools menu to access the management consoles for the installed Roles and Features.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to have missed the "Tools" dropdown in the top right of Server 2012 Server Manager, which has even more options than the built-in Server Manager 2008 R2 console. It will list any of the management consoles you currently have installed on the server.

[image]

Comment: My only complaint with that is I liked how everything was inside of a single "app" before - now the tools are all separated out like before. Just seems clunkier, but this Tools option will at least help some. Thanks!